# html email is not displaying in proper format in email (except gmail) when I send it using php mail function

Tags: php

I am new in php and trying to send email via php mail function. In gmail account email is displaying properly but other than gmail I received html tags as text in email body.

**Here is my code snippet:**

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= "Reply-To:abc@abc.com" . "\r\n";

$headers .= "BCC: $bcc" . "\r\n";

$headers .= "From: $from" . "\r\n";
```

**mail function which I am using is:**

```
mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers )
```

Comment: show your email template

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, I just replaced '\r\n' with '\n' and it started working perfectly for every mailbox.

Thanks